# Why won't my Nether Portal light?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I buld a nether portal and light it it wont light. The obsidian lights on fire but no portal please help me fix this.

Comment: How did you build your portal? Try to provide some more information so it's easier for us to help you.

Comment: Are you on single player?

Comment: @kutschkem Single play and multiplayer doesn't affect nether portal lighting, unless he's in a server.

Comment: @Jim I don't quite remember why I asked that, I think lighting the portal only works inside your claim on some servers with grief prevention

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your portal has a complete connection around an area that your charactor can pass through, like the picture below, before lighting it, or else the portal will not open. (Example is for a 4x5 portal frame)

[image]

*[Source of Photo](http://www.techgatherer.com/minecraft-xbox-360-edition-tips-tricks-and-achievement-guide/)*

Comment: Portals are no longer constrained to be only 2x3

Comment: ahh @SaintWacko thank you, did not know that!  Updated

Comment: I edited it slightly to clarify it. Feel free to revert if you feel it changes too much.